# Generalization of the Heckscher-Ohlin Model

Tags: reference-request, international-trade, environmental-economics

The [Heckscher-Ohlin Model](http://en.wikewipedia.org/wiki/Heckscher%E2%80%93Ohlin_model) is normally presented for the case of 2 countries, 2 factors of production and 2 traded goods, leading to statements that, subject to free trade and various other assumptions:

1. A country with a relative abundance of a factor will specialize in
   and export the good whose production makes relatively intensive use
   of that factor (the Heckscher-Ohlin Theorem).
2. The return to a factor will be equalized between the countries (the
   Factor Price Equalization or Heckscher-Ohlin-Samuelson Theorem).

Do these results generalize, subject to the same assumptions, to cases with more than 2 countries, factors or traded goods, and what are good sources that treat this topic?  Of particular interest are cases with 3 factors: labour, man-made capital and [natural capital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_capital).

I appreciate that the predictions of the Heckscher-Ohlin Model often differ from 
empirical findings (eg the [Leontief Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leontief_paradox)), but this question is about the model itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HO model has been generalised. Vanek does a good job of it.

Instead of only two countries, there is an index of countries.

- There are many industries.
- Identical technology
- Identical, homothetic tastes.

The HOV theorem states that if a country is abundant in a factor,
its factor content of trade in that factor should be positive, and
negative otherwise.

Empirically, this model is not that successful. [Here](http://www.nber.org/papers/w5625.pdf) is a good paper discussing the applications and results.

See below for that extension:
Vanek, Jaroslav, The Factor Proportions Theory: The N-Factor Case,” Kyklos, October 1968, 21, 749-755.